# Use FOR /F to search for variable in text file

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to add a small check to the start of a script. it involves having a user inputted variable %S% checked against a list stored in a text file. Can anyone suggest why the below code doesn't work and the best way to format the text file?

At the moment anything you type echoes not broke if its' on the list or not.
The list is currently formatted as simply comma seperated values eg [60001,60002,60003,60004,60005]

```
@echo off

SET STORES=c:\Stores.txt
SET /P S=What is the code [60***]?
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%S IN (%STORES%) DO GOTO FIND

ECHO BROKE

:FIND
ECHO NOT BROKE

PAUSE
```

Comment: You're not checking the value of `%S%` Your for loop is always going to go to `:Find`.

Comment: Thanks but i'm really not too familiar with the syntax of the FOR command. After seeing Thomas' answer below it makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I think you should avoid using %S% and %%S, because that's confusing.
Next I recommend changing the format of Stores.txt if you can do so. Put one number per line. Like this, you'll also get rid of the `delims=` option.

```
60001
60002
60003
60004
60005
```

Then, introduce an `IF` statement to check the user input against the file content. Finally, I think you need a `GOTO END` statements in the file to do what you expect. Here's the complete file:

```
@echo off

SET STORES=Stores.txt
SET /P USERINPUT=What is the code [60***]?
FOR /F "delims=," %%P IN (%STORES%) DO IF "%USERINPUT%"=="%%P" GOTO FIND

ECHO BROKE
GOTO END

:FIND
ECHO NOT BROKE

:END
PAUSE
```

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas, it makes sense now. this will work perfectly!

Comment: I notice you recommend separate lines but you still have comma in the delimiters.